# Problems with scanning

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

I'm studying Biomedical Informatics and I'm now doing my clinical practice, where I have to check that the charges made to hospitalized patients were performed correctly on supplies that are of ***unique charging*** (every procedure and supplies used have a codification).

I can import the Excel file on the software I'm doing but, I don't know now how to do the scan.
Here is the code (I'm doing it on NetBeans),

```
public class Portal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private DefaultTableModel model;
public static int con = 0;
public ArrayList listas = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList listasr = new ArrayList();

public Portal() {
    initComponents();
    model = new DefaultTableModel();
    jTable1.setModel(model);
}                             

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     JFileChooser examinar = new JFileChooser();
    examinar.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos Excel", "xls", "xlsx"));
    int opcion = examinar.showOpenDialog(this);
    File archivoExcel = null;

    if(opcion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

        archivoExcel = examinar.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
        try{
            Workbook leerExcel = Workbook.getWorkbook(archivoExcel);
            for (int hoja=0; hoja<leerExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); hoja++)
            {
                Sheet hojaP = leerExcel.getSheet(hoja);
                int columnas = hojaP.getColumns();
                int filas = hojaP.getRows();
                Object data[]= new Object[columnas];
                for (int fila=0; fila < filas; fila++)
                {
                    for(int columna=0; columna < columnas; columna++)
                    {
                        if(fila==0)
                        {
                            model.addColumn(hojaP.getCell(columna, fila).getContents());
                        }
                        System.out.println(hojaP.getCell(columna, fila).getContents());
                        if(fila>=1)
                        data[columna] = hojaP.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();  
                    }model.addRow(data);
                }
            }
            model.removeRow(0);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excel cargado exitosamente");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is severely underspecified so it will be next to impossible to help you.

Comment: Which behavior did you expect from that program? Which exact implementation problem are you having? What have you tried to do to solve the implementation problem so far? The scope of your project is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Before you import the excel file save it as a csv(comma delimited) file(remeber to delete the headings). Then open the netbeans project folder under my documents, then open the your project folder and dump the csv file in their. Look at your project under files in netbeans open the folder and you will see the file in their. Now you said you want to read the file/ scan the file.

You can use my method at first, understand it and adapt to other scenarios you have in the future.

First create a class or use an readily created( you already created java class).

Declare arrays depending on how many rows you had in the excel file not the csv file and a counter.
Example two.

```
 String [] patientsnamess;
    int [] ages;
    int count;
```

Now initiate the arrays in a deafault constructor(you don't have to because you can do it when you declare them but it is conventional). You can learn about constructors there are two I know of or there are only two but I will only show a default constructor.

It will look like this.

```
       public yourClassName(){
        patientsnames = new String[400];//the number in square brackets are an example it sets the size of the array. You can set the size according to how many patients there are or you could just use lists as the limit on the list as dependent on primary and virtual memory.
    ages = new int[400];
    count = 0;
}
```

now create the method two read the text file.

```
    public void readFile(){
    count = 0;//important
    Scanner contents = null;
    try{
    contents = new Scanner(new FileReader("You file's name.txt");
    while(contents.hasNext()){
    String a = contents.nextLine();
    String p[]= a.split("\\;");
    patientsnames[count] = p[0];
    ages[count] = p[1];
    count++;//important
    }
} 
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
    }
```

Now create get methods to call up the arrays with the values from the file.(Find out on rest of stackoverflow).
Remeber that field types link up with the data in the file.

I really hope this works for you. If not I am sorry but good luck with your Biochemical Informatics course.
Remeber to call the readFile method with an object in this case or it won't work.
Research the neccessary imports such as:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```